# how to check the name in textbox already exists as a folder in localhost server (PHP) not using mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
form.php

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $ageErr = $qualErr = $mobileErr = "";
$name = $age = $qual = $mobile = "";
$error="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["age"]))
     {$ageErr = "Age is required";}
   else
     {$age = test_input($_POST["age"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["qual"]))
     {$qualErr = "Qualification is required";}
   else
     {$qual = test_input($_POST["qual"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["mobile"]))
     {$mobileErr = "mobile Number is required";}
   else
     {$mobile = test_input($_POST["mobile"]);}
     if (empty($_POST["name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
   else
     {$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     if(file_exists($name)!=$name)
     {
    $ab=mkdir($name,0777);//creating folder in server side, entered name as folder name
    $c=realpath($name);//created folder path
    $d=$name.".txt";//creating text file which should come under folder with the same name 
    $sam="$c/".$d;
    $a=fopen($sam,'w+');
    $space="\r\n";
    $details=$name.$space.$age.$space.$qual.$space.$mobile;
    fwrite($a,$details);//inside text file information is stored

    }

     else
     {
         echo $name."\talready exists";

     }
     }

}
function test_input($data)
{

     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

     return $data;
}
?>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
form.html


<html>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
         $('#sub').click(function()
         {
             $("#formajax").submit(function(e)
         {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString=$("#formajax").serialize();


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:"form.php",
data:dataString,

success:function(data){
    alert("success");

},
error:function(data){
    alert("name already exists as a folder");
    }

})
return false;

});
});
});

</script>    
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="formajax"  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<pre>
NAME         :<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br/>
AGE          :<input type="text" name="age" id="age"><span class="error">*<?php echo $ageErr;?></span><br/>
QUALIFICATION:<input type="text" name="qual" id="qual"><span class="error">*<?php echo $qualErr;?></span><br/>
MOBILE       :<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mob"><span class="error">*<?php echo $mobileErr;?></span>
<br/>

              <input id="sub" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
<pre>
</form>
</body>
```

when i execute this code,after entering details folder is created inside the folder text file is created,inside text file information is stored...both folder and text file name is created with user entered name..if it already exists then it doesnot created with that name....now i'm getting alert message like success even name is alredy exits..
i cant get name already exists message through alert..
pl find out the mistake and reply 
thanks

Answer (score 3):

File exists function is called incorrectly (it returns boolean)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
if(file_exists($name)!=$name)
```

should be replaced with

```
if(!file_exists($name))
```

Comment: Good call, just beat me to it :)

Comment: still it shows success message only..when i entered already existing name,it should show name already exists message

Comment: can you log the post body using print_r($_POST);

Comment: In your php file, can you add -
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
print_r($_POST); Please mention the output

Comment: NAME         :xxx
AGE          :xxx
QUALIFICATION:xxx
MOBILE       :xxx
after submitting this i get success in alert box at the same time in my localhost one folder is created with the name of xxx inside text file created with the name of xxx inside details stored.

Comment: if again i entered the name xxx and submit the form i am getting success alert box instead of name already exists alert box and the folder which is created earlier is not affected and no new folder is created..